# Is there a way to open URL in android with new activity stack?

Tags: android, web

I would like to open web url from my app to show in browser, but i want to do so that user doesn't need to click "back" to go to my app and can use multitask button. So the activity stack of my app stays independent of the browser.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try this:

Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);

That works fine for me.
 As for the missing "http://" I'd just do something like this:
if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
url = "http://" + url;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the activity stack issue.

Comment: How about `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` ?

Comment: @CodeWalker Thanks! That did it, can you post it as separate answer, so I can check it as correct?

Comment: @Punga - Check my answer! Accept and up-vote it if it helped you :)